# Error al querer utilizar com.android.support:design:28.0.0

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

Agregue la siguiente linea a mi archivo gradle

```
implementacion 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

Al sincronizar me sale el siguiente mensaje

```
ERROR: Could not find method implementacion() for arguments [com.android.support:design:28.0.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
Open Android SDK Manager
```

Revise el SDK Manager y creo que tengo todo lo necesario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está mal escrito el implementation

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```